# StaticCompressionModule and DynamicCompressionModule on 32bit IIS and 64bit Windows

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I want to host a 32bit application in IIS 7 on 64 bit Windows 2008. When I visit the site with the default modules enabled I get this error -

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
Module: DynamicCompressionModule
Notification: SendResponse 
Handler: StaticFile 
Error Code: 0x8007007e
```

If I remove the StaticCompressionModule and DynamicCompressionModule the site works.

Can I get it working without having to disable these modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I couldn't get it to work without disabling these two modules. It's worth noting that if you're using Visual Studio to deploy your application to an IIS server, your applications config is going to overwrite what is on the server and thus, reenable the two modules. You need to disable the modules in your config file.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft KB says

> This problem occurs because the ApplicationHost.config file or the Web.config file references a module or a DLL that is invalid or that does not exist.

Try enabling 32bit application in Application Pool configuration

EDIT:

Found the folowing

> For above specific error (mentioned in this example), DynamicCompressionModule module is causing the trouble. This is because of the XPress compression scheme module (suscomp.dll) which gets installed with WSUS. Since Compression schemes are defined globally and try to load in every application Pool, it will result in this error when 64bit version of suscomp.dll attempts to load in an application pool which is running in 32bit mode.
>
> > This module entry looks like:
> >
> > Hence to get rid of this problem:
> >
> > Ø Remove/Disable the XPress compression scheme from the configuration using the command below:
> >
> > %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /-[name='xpress']
> >
> > OR
> >
> > Ø Use a 32bit version of suscomp.dll

Comment: I already enabled it. Site works without those two modules I mentioned. Both DLLs exist in the windows\system32\inetsrv folder.

Comment: 32bit version is here C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\suscomp.dll right where it should be. I'm trying to avoid globally disabling things on the IIS server since it's the company server and it hosts other applications.